# Dynamic WordPress rewrite rules for multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

I'm very new to WordPress development and would like some pointers if this is possible.

So I have this rewrite rule for my custom sidebar in functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'cpt_rewrite');
function cpt_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^recipe/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?','index.php?post_type=recipe&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^recipe/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type=recipe&year=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^faq/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?','index.php?post_type=faq&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^faq/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type=faq&year=$matches[1]','top');

// ... and more

}
```

The thing is, this project has more than 10 custom post types (possibly more) and each post type has the same rule. So every time I add more custom post type, I have to add two more lines in the functions.php file to apply the same rule for that new post type. Is there any way to iterate these rules and have the post type slugs dynamically added?

Something like this, perhaps (though this does not work):

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^'.$post_type.'/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^'.$post_type.'/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&year=$matches[1]','top');
```

Comment: Why doesn’t your example work? If you’ve defined `$post_type` then it should work. You could just create an array of post types and then loop through each of them as `$post_type`.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie, I solved it now! The reason why it didn't work before is because I was using the `get_post_type()` function instead of `get_post_types()` and not looping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob's comment got me on the right track.

Here's what worked for my issue:

```
add_action('init', 'cpt_rewrite');
function cpt_rewrite(){
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
    );

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args );
    if ( $post_types ) {
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            add_rewrite_rule('^'.$post_type.'/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');
            add_rewrite_rule('^'.$post_type.'/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&year=$matches[1]','top'); 
        }
    }
}
```

I used [get_post_types()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/) to get all my registered custom post types and then loop through each of them.